# Como ler o que o usuário digitou em um formulário?

Tags: php, html5, if

O código está assim:

```
<form method="post" action="pagina.php"/>
<?php
$c= 1;
$neg = 0;
    while($c <=3){
        echo "Digite um numero: <input type='number' name='$num' min='1'/>";
            if($num < $neg){
                $total++;
                }
            $c++;
            }
?>
<input type='submit' value='Resultado'/>
```

Não estou sabendo como fazer o que o usuario digitou, se torna uma variável para eu poder usar a estrutura de controle nele. Tentei colocando uma variável direto no name ($num), mas parece que não deu certo ou não é assim. Ou esse tipo de coisa é para JavaScript ?

Comment: Sugeriria ler as paginas introdutórias do manual do PHP. Não faz nenhum sentido seu código. PHP não é uma linguagem que naturalmente interage com usuário quando usada via HTML e navegador. PHP só monta coisas estáticas. O cliente recebe o conteúdo, e se quiser interagir, tem que chamar um novo PHP (ou o mesmo, mas numa nova execução). Comece por aqui, com atenção aos detalhes: http://us3.php.net/manual/pt_BR/getting-started.php - Se tiver facilidade com inglês, melhor ainda, a documentação em português tem menos qualidade (mas para o básico já serve)

Comment: se você quer saber o que está escrito no formulário, basta usar javascript,

$("form").val();

Caso queira pegar em php, basta enviar o formulario via ajax ou pra uma pagina e transformar em variavel, usando metodos POST ou GET

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um exemplo simples de formulário gerado dinamicamente com PHP:

pagina_um.php

```
<form method="post" action="pagina_dois.php">
<?php
    for( $c = 1; $c <= 3; ++$c) {
        echo "   Digite um numero: <input type='text' name='input_$n'>";
    }
?>
   <input type='submit' value='Resultado'>
</form>
```

pagina_dois.php

```
<?php
    $total = 0;
    for( $c = 1; $c <= 3; ++$c) {
        $total = $total + $_POST["input_$n"];
    }
    echo "O total é $total";
?>
```

Note que são duas etapas. A primeira, gerando o formulário. A segunda, recebendo o resultado do formulário.

Não fiz nenhuma proteção para verificar se os dados fazem sentido, por ser apenas um exemplo elementar. Numa aplicação prática, precisa de uma série de cuidados extra.

Basicamente, quando você tem um `form` com método `POST`, tem que pegar usando a variável global `$_POST['nomedocampo']`.

Answer (score 1):

Caso queira pegar o que o usuário digitou na `pagina.php`, basta usar os métodos GET ou POST do PHP! Como você declarou o metodo POST no formulário, basta chamar a função `$_POST['']` na `pagina.php`.

Também pode fazer isso com JavaScript, mas, na mesma página, criando intervalos de alguns segundos, dá para criar um preview do texto que o usuário fez.

- ***Dica***

Remova o código php do seu formulário, não faz sentido esse código!
E crie um `input` normal em HTML, e o `name`, coloque de sua preferência. Como "number" por exemplo.

### Exemplos

**PHP (pagina.php)**

```
$number = $_POST['number'];
echo ($number);
//vai aparecer o que o usuário digitou ao clicar no Resultado.
```

**JavaScript (página do formulário)**

```
$("#butaum").click(function() {

  var number = $('#number').val();

  $("#resultado").html(number);

});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type='number' id="number" name='number' min='1'>
</form>

<button id="butaum" >Resultado</button>

<div id="resultado">


</div>
```